# Problems at Flutter/Dart Unit Test development

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to code the Unit Test for my `DataSourceImpl` class, but I'm facing a problem with the methods that are called into the testing method.

I mocked and set the return for all methods into the DataSource testing method with the `when` statement, but it's not working...

Into the `save` and `remove` methods the Stream is called to notify the changes.

I'm using `mocktail: ^0.1.4` for mocking dependency objects.

**DATASOURCE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
class DocumentDataSourceImpl implements IDocumentDataSource {
  final FlutterSecureStorage _storage;
  final StreamController<List<DocumentModel>> _streamController;

  DocumentDataSourceImpl(this._storage, this._streamController);

  @override
  Future<void> remove(String id) async {
    try {
      await _storage.delete(key: id);
      _streamController.sink.add(await getAll());
    } catch (e) {
      throw DocumentNotRemovedException();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> save(DocumentModel model) async {
    try {
      await _storage.write(key: model.id, value: json.encode(model.toJson()));
      _streamController.sink.add(await getAll());
    } catch (e) {
      throw DocumentNotSavedException();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<List<DocumentModel>> getAll() async {
    final result = await _storage.readAll();
    return result.entries
        .map((e) => DocumentModel.fromJson(json.decode(e.value)))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

**UNIT TEST**

```
void main() {
  // Global Definitions
  //-----Main Objects
  late FlutterSecureStorageMock storage;
  late StreamControllerMock<List<DocumentModel>> streamController;
  late DocumentDataSourceImpl dataSource;

  // SetUp Test
  setUp(() {
    //-----Objects Initialization
    storage = FlutterSecureStorageMock();
    streamController = StreamControllerMock();
    dataSource = DocumentDataSourceImpl(storage, streamController);
  });

  group(("DocumentDataSource: Remove"), () {
    final tArgument = "Document 1";
    test("[P] Should remove the DocumentModel on Storage", () async {
      //-----Arrange
      when(() => storage.readAll())
          .thenAnswer((_) async => tDocumentModelListMap);

      when(() => dataSource.getAll())
          .thenAnswer((_) async => tDocumentModelList);

      when(() => streamController.sink.add(tDocumentModelList));

      when(() => storage.delete(key: tArgument)).thenAnswer((_) async => null);

      //-----Act
      dataSource.remove(tArgument);

      //-----Assert
      verify(() => storage.delete(key: tArgument)).called(1);
      verify(() => streamController.sink.add(tDocumentModelList)).called(1);
    });

    test(
        "[N] Should return a DocumentNotRemovedException when the call of Storage is unsuccessful.",
        () async {
      //-----Arrange
      when(() => storage.delete(key: tArgument)).thenThrow(
        GenericExceptionMock(),
      );

      //-----Act
      final result = dataSource.remove(tArgument);

      //-----Assert
      expect(result, throwsA(DocumentNotRemovedException()));
      verify(() => storage.delete(key: tArgument)).called(1);
      verifyNever(() => streamController.sink.add(tDocumentModelList));
    });
  });

  group(("DocumentDataSource: Save"), () {
    final tArgument = tDocumentModel;
    test("[P] Should save the DocumentModel on Storage", () async {
      //-----Arrange
      when(() => storage.readAll())
          .thenAnswer((_) async => tDocumentModelListMap);

      when(() => dataSource.getAll())
          .thenAnswer((_) async => tDocumentModelList);

      when(() => streamController.sink.add(tDocumentModelList));

      when(() => storage.write(
          key: tArgument.id, value: json.encode(tArgument.toJson())));

      //-----Act
      dataSource.save(tArgument);

      //-----Assert
      verify(() => storage.write(
          key: tArgument.id, value: json.encode(tArgument.toJson()))).called(1);
      // verify(() => realTimeEvents.update(tDocumentModelList)).called(1);
    });

    test(
        "[N] Should return a DocumentNotSavedException when the call of Storage is unsuccessful.",
        () async {
      //-----Arrange
      when(() => storage.write(
          key: tArgument.id, value: json.encode(tArgument.toJson()))).thenThrow(
        GenericExceptionMock(),
      );

      //-----Act
      final result = dataSource.save(tArgument);

      //-----Assert
      expect(result, throwsA(DocumentNotSavedException()));
      verify(() => storage.write(
          key: tArgument.id, value: json.encode(tArgument.toJson()))).called(1);
      verifyNever(() => streamController.sink.add(tDocumentModelList));
    });
  });
}
```

**MOCKS**

```
class FlutterSecureStorageMock extends Mock implements FlutterSecureStorage {}

class StreamControllerMock<T> extends Mock implements StreamController<T> {}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Map<String, String>>'
FlutterSecureStorageMock.readAll
DocumentDataSourceImpl.getAll
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
when.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                                                     _completeOnAsyncError
package:memo/features/data/datasources/document_datasource_impl.dart           DocumentDataSourceImpl.getAll
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
when.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>

Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response
when
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>

✖ DocumentDataSource: Remove [P] Should remove the DocumentModel on Storage
Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response
when
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>

✖ DocumentDataSource: Remove [N] Should return a DocumentNotRemovedException when the call of Storage is unsuccessful.
Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response
when
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>

✖ DocumentDataSource: Save [P] Should save the DocumentModel on Storage
Bad state: Cannot call `when` within a stub response
when
main.<fn>.<fn>
main.<fn>.<fn>

✖ DocumentDataSource: Save [N] Should return a DocumentNotSavedException when the call of Storage is unsuccessful.
Exited (1)
```

Comment: Any chance we could take a look at the code that defines your Mock subclasses as well?  I have a vague inkling that we might find the answer there, but am not sure...

Comment: Yeah, I will edit with the mock code... thanks :)